# "For loop" to check elements of a CheckBoxList

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

What am I doing wrong? I have a CheckBoxList and I want to handle each element one by one. I get an error on the "cbl.Items.Count" line suggested the element is not initialized with "new". Thanks you very much!

```
CheckBoxList cbl = (CheckBoxList)FindControl("CBL_categ");
for (int i = 0; i < cbl.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (cbl.Items[i].Selected)
        catn = cbl.Items[i].Value;
}
```

EDIT:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" runat="server" 
    contentplaceholderid="ContentPlaceHolder3">
    <asp:Label ID="statusLabel" runat="server" Text=""> </asp:Label>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Visible="False" >
        ....

    </asp:GridView>


    <br />
    Categories:<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CBL_categ" runat="server" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="name">
    </asp:CheckBoxList>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Did you check to see if it actually found the control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an error check in there because it may be returning null.

```
CheckBoxList cbl = (CheckBoxList)FindControl("CBL_categ");

if (cbl != null)
{
        for (int i = 0; i < cbl.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (cbl.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                catn = cbl.Items[i].Value;
             }
         }
 }
```

Comment: You were right, thank you. The control isn't found. If I add (cbl!=null), no error is returned. How can I make sure it finds it. The checkboxlist is placed directly onto the placeholder.

Comment: Check that you have the correct spelling. If you have then I would suggest placing a breakpoint in your code and stepping through it line by line. Dont forget to select this as your accepted answer :)

Comment: Thanks! The spelling is correct. Not sure how to use breakpoints. Is it possible to get a message box to show up to check the value of different elements at different times?

Comment: Did you look at the other answer above as well? It could be due to it being in another container. So you first need to find that container and then your control within that. I would strongly suggest you need to learn how to use breakpoints for debugging. If you are going to be a programmer you will need it, a lot! :)

Comment: The container is a placeholder called ContentPlaceHolder3. Should I add that? FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder3").FindControl("CBL_categ"). Will give it a try and be back.

Comment: Unfortunately I get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`: for line `CheckBoxList cbl = FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder3").FindControl("CBL_categ") as CheckBoxList;`

Comment: Can you post any of the HTML?

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the fact that I populate the CBL in Page_Load like this: `if (!Page.IsPostBack) 
            {
                CBL_categ.DataSource = ShopAccess.Pop_check();
                CBL_categ.DataBind();
            }`

Comment: Try CheckBoxList cbl = FindControl("Content4").FindControl("CBL_categ")

Comment: My God! I am exhausted. I think I tried all the possible combinations so far. It worked like this: `ContentPlaceHolder mpContentPlaceHolder = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder3");
            CheckBoxList cbl = (CheckBoxList)mpContentPlaceHolder.FindControl("CBL_categ");` I am guilty of having omitted a "small" detail for fear of overburdening the question and making it unreadable: the CBL was on a placeholder that was on a master page! Thank you so very much for your time!

Comment: If you want to shorten it down a little, you should be able to use `cbl = (CheckBoxList)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder3").FindControl("CBL_categ");`

Answer (score 2):

A common cause of this is that if the CheckBoxList you're looking for is nested inside some other container, FindControl won't find it as it doesn't search recursively and will instead return null.

If it is being nested, the best performance solution is something like:

```
FindControl("nestingcontrol").FindControl("CBL_categ")
```

Alternatively, write a recursive method that runs a FindControl on each control, but expect a performance hit.

> Reference:
>
> http://forums.asp.net/t/1107107.aspx